Xcode 15.3, use xcodebuild to build app, error: "TARGET" requires a provisioning profile xxxxx
Everything is ok util upgrade to xcode15.3 and macos14.0.
When I use xcodebuild to build my app, some error occured:
error: "ShopAssistant" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'ShopAssistant' from project 'ShopAssistant')
But, just use Xcode menu Product/Archive is ok. I need to use command line in our CI/CD system. Hope somebody can help me.

Terminal Log Details:
xcodebuild -project ShopAssistant.xcodeproj -scheme ShopAssistant -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive
Command line invocation:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project ShopAssistant.xcodeproj -scheme ShopAssistant -sdk iphoneos -configuration Release archive

User defaults from command line:
    IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES

Build settings from command line:
    SDKROOT = iphoneos17.4

--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-0009489814FB001E, name:My Mac }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E06C0B90-67C7-449D-981E-0BFEEDF77160, OS:17.4, name:iPad (10th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:E06C0B90-67C7-449D-981E-0BFEEDF77160, OS:17.4, name:iPad (10th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:35BC8560-1097-4751-A0F5-F6DC0B4C84DE, OS:17.4, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:35BC8560-1097-4751-A0F5-F6DC0B4C84DE, OS:17.4, name:iPad Air (5th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1150700F-45CA-42E4-8D8B-8E70C849886E, OS:17.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:1150700F-45CA-42E4-8D8B-8E70C849886E, OS:17.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (4th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5BA4C379-2462-449F-9D93-5D64DED7422E, OS:17.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:5BA4C379-2462-449F-9D93-5D64DED7422E, OS:17.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F2F80E23-7C33-4965-806D-EC56962ECE54, OS:17.4, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:F2F80E23-7C33-4965-806D-EC56962ECE54, OS:17.4, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C5A161D8-1D8B-499A-BB27-3B630002CE25, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:C5A161D8-1D8B-499A-BB27-3B630002CE25, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:995C11EA-5ACF-4A1A-9FFC-DF0A0AEE63F2, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:995C11EA-5ACF-4A1A-9FFC-DF0A0AEE63F2, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Plus }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3A444CC6-16B1-4F79-8144-7A5BB23FD1BA, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3A444CC6-16B1-4F79-8144-7A5BB23FD1BA, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D30229CD-1D9E-4206-980E-70A5208E5193, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:D30229CD-1D9E-4206-980E-70A5208E5193, OS:17.4, name:iPhone 15 Pro Max }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C53C988-D93B-4E38-AC9F-BE8B8F111280, OS:17.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
{ platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C53C988-D93B-4E38-AC9F-BE8B8F111280, OS:17.4, name:iPhone SE (3rd generation) }
Prepare packages

ComputeTargetDependencyGraph
note: Building targets in dependency order
note: Target dependency graph (1 target)
    Target 'ShopAssistant' in project 'ShopAssistant' (no dependencies)

GatherProvisioningInputs

CreateBuildDescription

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk -x c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/ibtool --version --output-format xml1

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --print-asset-tag-combinations --output-format xml1 /Users/es/ShopAssistant_3.7.9/shopassistant_native_ios_pure/930714_0_4.9.3/Assistant/Images.xcassets

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --version --output-format xml1

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -v

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -v -E -dM -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.4.sdk -x c -c /dev/null

ExecuteExternalTool /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld -version_details

Build description signature: xxxxxxx
Build description path: /Users/es/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ShopAssistant-cmrxpudshqxyfcgqsharjobmjuxt/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/ShopAssistant/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/xxxxxx.xcbuilddata
/Users/ShopAssistant.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 9.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.4.99. (in target 'ShopAssistant' from project 'ShopAssistant')
/Users/ShopAssistant.xcodeproj: error: "ShopAssistant" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains, Push Notifications, and Sign in with Apple features. Select a provisioning profile in the Signing & Capabilities editor. (in target 'ShopAssistant' from project 'ShopAssistant')
** ARCHIVE FAILED **

use fastlane or xcodebuild, "xxx" requires a provisioning profile xxxxx occured.
Maybe that is a bug?
